# Why I can't use AJAX to post JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass JavaScript variables to the PHP file using the AJAX post method. My console returns: `'ok'`, but if I enter a `file.php`, I have only display the white page. Why?

```
$(".btn_ranking").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
  var time = localStorage.getItem('timer_end');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/file.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      name: name,
      time: time,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('ok');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

---

```
<?php  

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];    
    echo $name;
}

?>
```

Comment: You go to `file.php` *separately, after* sending the AJAX request? Well, no, that page won't contain the value. Open you browser's developer tools' network inspector and look at the AJAX network request and its response instead.

Comment: @deceze, your reason is working, but I have: Request Payload: `name=Adrian&time=00%3A01%3A13`. I need `name=Adrian&time=00:01:13`. How Can I change this?

Comment: @Adrian12 — Why do you need the URL to not be **properly** encoded?

Comment: because I want `name=Adrian&time=00:01:13` transfer to mysql using php query

Comment: Values need to be *properly URL encoded*. How they end up in the database is a completely separate story. It's incomprehensible at this moment what problem you are facing exactly.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important things to remember about Ajax is that it **does not cause the browser to navigate to a new page**.

The entire point of Ajax is that it makes an HTTP request and, instead of doing what the browser would normally do with the response, makes the response available to JavaScript.

---

If you want to display the response to an Ajax request, then you have to write JavaScript that will display it.

It will be available in the `response` variable (the first argument of the `success` method … which needs to be a property of the object you pass to `ajax()` and not a property of the `data` object … so how "OK" is showing up in your console, I have no idea).

You can then add it to the document (`$(document.body).append(response)` as a simple example).

---

That said, if you want to render it as a whole new document, the best approach is to **not use Ajax** in the first place.

Create a form with the data in it, append it to the document, then submit it.